# Please guide me to set an attribute in XML node usig MSXML. I am struck

Tags: msxml, setattribute

---

I try to set an attribute in a XML node using MSXML.
IXMLDOMElement alone has the member function setatrribute. So i got the document element.

```
pXMLDocumentElement->get_documentElement(&pElement);
pElement->selectSingleNode(nodePathString,&pNode);
.
.
.
pElement->setAttribute(bstr,var);
```

I selected the required node inwhich the attribute has to be set using selectsinglenode funcion.
after selecting the required node, i tried to set attribute.

But the PElement pointer doesnot shift to the required node. it stayed on the root node. 
Result: added the attribute in root itself

Is ther any way, I can shift my PElement to the node resulted in selectsinglenode function.
so that i can set the attribute,.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

pNode->setAttribute(bstr,var);

Comment: Sad, provision is not given such :(